# a problem with the area locked SIM card, how can I unlock my iphone?

Tags: ios, unlock, sim

I recently updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 7; however, I need to fully unlock my iPhone (which I inserted a SIM card into). How do I do this?
Note: my sim card is from Tahiti (French Polynesia). Can you help me resolve this problem?

Comment: The way to unlock a carrier-locked phone is to ring the carrier that locked it.

Comment: This post has been machine translated - it might need an edit for clarity if the translation was poor.

Comment: Improved translation, no need for further edits to improve the English.

Comment: And yes, kainalu, you should call your carrier and ask about unlocking your phone. If you think there is a chance that your phone's contract period is over, just Google "[your phone carrier] check iPhone upgrade eligibility" or head to your carrier's website. Note that if you have AT&T, Sprint, or Verizon, you can follow the instructions here: http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971568

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just call up your network carrier and they can unlock it. I had the same thing. Just be prepared to wait couple weeks as the carriers say it takes up to 3 weeks to unlock. Or you can use a third party site like http://unlockingofficial.com I used this site couple times and worked great. It still takes a few days to get unlock though.